# Rails: How do I create a clustered index on a non-id column in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I want to store time series data in a database. The data will be organized as follows:

- A header table has information about a dataset (format, source, etc). Typically a dataset will have about 600 rows.
- A "Big Data" table has the actual rows of data. Each row will have a header_id, timestamp, and some data points.

I'm trying to create a table with a clustered index on a data_header_id column instead of the id column. This is so that I can get all of the data points by doing a simple `SELECT * FROM big_datums WHERE data_header_id = 9001 ORDER BY timestamp ASC`.

I have the following code, but get errors because of Rails defaults:

```
class CreateBigData < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    create_table :headers do |t|
      t.string :data_format
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :big_datums do |t|
      t.references :data_header, null: false # This will need to be a CLUSTED index
      t.integer :timestamp
      t.integer :point1
      t.integer :point2
    end

    execute "CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [data-header-index] ON [dbo].[big_datums] ( [data_header_id] ASC )
             WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
             ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]"
    end
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP INDEX [data-header-index] ON [dbo].[big_datums] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )"
    drop_table :big_datums
    drop_table :headers
  end
end
```

I get this error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.big_datums'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK__build_te__3213E83F6568EFB2' before creating another.

This appears to be because rails already gives id a clustered PK.

Questions:

1) How do I create a table as described?

2) Do I still need an 'id' column? I won't ever be querying by an ID column, but it might still be good to have a PK column to uniquely identify records -- especially since header_id + timestamp might not be a good clustered PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drop the PK constraint first.  And you probably should just replace the existing clustered PK with one a compound clustered index on (data_header_id,id).

EG

```
use tempdb 

go
drop table if exists big_datums 
go

create table big_datums
(
  id int identity primary key,
  data_header_id int not null
)

go

declare @pkname sysname = (select name from sys.key_constraints where type = 'PK' and parent_object_id = object_id('big_datums'))

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('alter table big_datums drop constraint [', @pkname,']')
--print (@sql)
exec (@sql)

alter table big_datums
add constraint pk_big_dautms
primary key clustered (data_header_id,id)
```

Clustered Indexes are always unique under the covers. SQL Server will add a hidden "uniqifier" column to the index in case of duplicates. So you end up with a similar, but more useful clustered index if you supply the second key column that makes it unique.   And if you have no other reason to have an index on `id` your table can use a single data structure.

Comment: Wow, the @David Browne! What would be the benefit of having a compound clustered index on both ID & header_id? The typical use case would be pulling in all data associated with a specified header_id - I can't see any reason to ever pull in a record just by its id.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. What do you mean by single data structure?

Comment: If you have a clustered index on data_header_id and a primary key on id, then you will have two BTree indexes, one for each.  Both data structures need to be updated when you perform DML on the table.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a `clustered index` on `big_datums`, there can be only `clustered index` on a table, because it defines the physical structure of data (how the data is store etc.). You can create a nonclustered index to support your query or just leave the existing index. You can have many of them an they are additional structures to your clustered index/heap.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [data-header-index] ON [dbo].[big_datums] ( [data_header_id] ASC )
```

It's good to have a unique key in your `clustered index`, because in other case sql server will add some overhead to your 8kb pages to make rows unique.

Comment: I'm going to be adding about 150k rows per day. Wouldn't it be more space/lookup speed efficient to have a clustered index on header_id?

Comment: If header_id will be used for joins, where and look-ups go for it. It's sounds like ever-increasing, so it's also good.